# Como capturar el valor de un select en Ionic, AngularJs?

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli, ionic

el problema se presenta al pasar el valor de un select, que quiero luego al cuando ng-change detecte un cambio se envie una petición con el valor del id dela provincia seleccionada, para luego devolver la ciudades según la provincia, pero al mostrar ese id en la vista no hay problema , si no que cuando lo paso en el controlador me sale undefined

ESTA ES LA VISTA

```
    <ion-view title="Page" id="page6" style="" ng-controller="inicioCtrl">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="page-form1" class="list">
    <label class="item item-select" id="page-select1">
    <span >Región</span>
    <select ng-options="elemento.nombreRegion for elemento in region" ng-model="reg">
           <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label class="item item-select" id="page-select2">
    <span class="input-label">Provincia</span>
    <select ng-model="pro" ng-change="cargarCiudades()" ng-options="item.idProvincia as item.nombreProvincia for item in provincias" >
        <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-select" id="page-select3">
    <span class="input-label">Comuna o Ciudad</span>
    <select ng-model="ciu" ng-options="item.idCiudad as item.nombreCiudad for item in ciudad" >
        <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <div id="page-container1" class="creator-container"></div>
</form>
    <!-- AQUI HAGO MIS PRUBAS DONDE SE MUETRAN LOS ID Y FUNCIONAN PERFECTO -->
<h1>{{reg.idRegion}}{{pro}}</h1>
<button id="page-button1" class="button button-positive  button-block">Guardar</button>
```

ESTE ES MI ARCHIVO DE CONTROLADORES

```
   angular.module('lista.controllers', [])

   .controller('inicioCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams','$http', 
   function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

   var rutaUno = '//127.0.0.1/0/chileAlerta/datos.php';

 $http.post(rutaUno,{ accion : 'obtenerRegiones'})
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.contenido.regiones);
        $scope.region = data.contenido.regiones;
        //console.log(data.contenido.usuarios);
        //$scope.posts = data.contenido.usuarios;
    })
    .error(function(readyStatelt){
        console.log(readyStatelt);
        //console.log(textStatus);
        //console.log(errorThrown);

    });


$http.post(rutaUno,{ accion : 'obtenerProvincias'})
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.contenido.provincias);
        $scope.provincias = data.contenido.provincias;

        //console.log(data.contenido.usuarios);
        //$scope.posts = data.contenido.usuarios;
    })
    .error(function(readyStatelt){
        console.log(readyStatelt);
        //console.log(textStatus);
        //console.log(errorThrown);

    });

    //console.log($scope.pro);
   $scope.cargarCiudades = function(){
   alert($scope.pro);
  obtenerCiudades($http,$scope,$scope.pro);

   }

   function obtenerCiudades($http,$scope,idProvincia){

 console.log(idProvincia);
 $http.post(rutaUno,{ accion : 'obtenerCiudad','idPro': idProvincia})
    .success(function(data,status,headers,cofing){
        console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(cofing);

    })
    .error(function(readyStatelt){
        console.log(readyStatelt);


    });
   }

   }]);
```

Y ESTE ES MI PHP EN EL SERVIDOR

```
   <?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
//incluimos el script de conexion a la base de datos
include_once 'class.Conexion.php';
//declaramos la conexion


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$accion = ($data->accion);
$salidaJson = "";
$contenido = array();
$estado = false;
$existe = false;

   if($accion == 'obtenerProvincias'){

   getProvincias();

  }elseif($accion == 'obtenerCiudad'){

$idProvincia = (object)($data->idPro);
getCiudades($idProvincia);

    }else if($accion == 'obtenerRegiones'){

getRegiones();      

   }

   function getRegiones(){

 $db = new Conexion();
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM regiones");

            if($db->rows($sql)> 0){

                $contenido['regiones'] = array();

                while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){

                    $region = array();

                    $region = array(
                        'idRegion' => $rew['id_region'],
                        'nombreRegion' => $rew['name_region']
                    );
                     array_push($contenido['regiones'],$region);
                }
                $existe = true;
                $estado  = true;
            }else{
                $estado = false;
                $existe = false;
            }
$salidaJson = array("contenido" => $contenido,
                   "estado" => $estado,
                   "existe" => $existe);

//header('Context-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($salidaJson);
  } 


   function getProvincias(){

 $db = new Conexion();
 $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM provincias");

            if($db->rows($sql)> 0){

                $contenido['provincias'] = array();

                while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){

                    $provincia = array();

                    $provincia = array(
                        'idProvincia' => $rew['id_provincia'],
                        'nombreProvincia' => $rew['nombre_provincia']
                    );
                     array_push($contenido['provincias'],$provincia);
                }
                $existe = true;
                $estado  = true;
            }else{
                $estado = false;
                $existe = false;
            }

    $salidaJson = array("contenido" => $contenido,
                   "estado" => $estado,
                   "existe" => $existe);

//header('Context-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($salidaJson);
  }


   function getCiudades($idProvincia){

  $db = new Conexion();
  /* $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ciudades WHERE id_provincia=".$idProvincia."");

            if($db->rows($sql)> 0){

                $contenido['ciudades'] = array();

                while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){

                    $provincia = array();

                    $ciudades = array(
                        'idCiudad' => $rew['id_ciudad'],
                        'nombreCiudad' => $rew['nombre_ciudad']
                    );
                     array_push($contenido['ciudades'],$ciudades);
                }
                $existe = $idProvincia;
                $estado  = true;
            }else{
                $estado = false;
                $existe = false;
            }*/
$estado = false;
$existe = false;
$contenido = var_dump($idProvincia);/* este es el que se devuelve como erro <br />
  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$idPro in <b>C:\dagg\htdocs\0\chileAlerta\datos.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
  object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
  }
  {"contenido":null,"estado":false,"existe":false}*/
$salidaJson = array("contenido" => $contenido,
                   "estado" => $estado,
                   "existe" => $existe);

//header('Context-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($salidaJson);
   }






   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `ng-model = pro` tiene ya el valor de tu `<select>`, lo otro es que no es necesario que declares una función y envíes por parámetro `$http`

Mientras que tu `ng-options` deberia ser algo asi :

```
ng-options="item as item.nombreProvincia for item in items track by item.idProvincia"
```

Teniendo en cuanto que `items` es tu arreglo con la lista de provincias

El `$scope.pro` tiene la misma estructura que tus datos, por lo tanto si tu dato ciudad por ejemplo fuera :

```
{
    idProvincia: 1,
    nombreProvincia: 'Provincia'
}
```

Puedes acceder al valor de la `id` con `$scope.pro.idProvincia`

```
.controller('inicioCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams','$http', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $scope.cargarCiudades = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '//127.0.0.1/0/chileAlerta/datos.php',
            data : {accion: 'obtenerCiudad', 'idPro': $scope.pro.idProvincia}

        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: A pesar de que ya lo solucione, gracias por la ayuda, la explicación super clara.

Comment: Me alegro @Dagg suerte!

Comment: te podria hacer consultas por un correo o face??? o es muy balsa?? XD

Comment: En estos momentos no puedo! Pero mañana con gusto te ayudo ya que no estoy en un pc

Comment: genial, y por que medio te puedo pedir ayuda??

Comment: Que necesitas? No se si por aqui pueda darte un contacto pero dime en que te puedo ayudar

Comment: buu que no necesito XD, pero orientacion con lo que es firebase, no se si lo has utilizado??

Comment: @Dagg no he ocupado firebase, pero que necesitas especificamente? sabes ocuparlo o quieres aprender de 0?

Comment: estoy aprendiendo a ocuparlo, pero enrealidad mas me interesa aprender bn angular a usar la directivas, recomiendas un libro o algo por ahi ???

Comment: @Dagg hay un tutorial de youtube de Jesus Conde que explica muy bien angularjs y despues puedes aprender angular2

Comment: verdad que ya van super avanzados y yo recien aprendiendo angulajs :/

Comment: tengo una problema justamente ahora, que es el rellenar una select con datos entregados de firebase, firebase entrega unos objetos, qu no puedo cargar,

Comment: creo que formulare otra pregunta mejor

Comment: @Dagg es lo mejor , en la comunidad hay mucha gente que te puede ayudar! El tutorial tiene desde el capitulo 1!! Buscalo te servira bastante!